# Is there any way to consume Odata and make an insert and update?

Tags: odata

I saw that we can only use read and query with Odata in SFDC with External source Objects 
is there any way we can make an insert or update using Odata Web services ?

Thank you and sorry is this was already answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Winter 16 we are getting [Writable External Objects](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_forcecom_external_data_writeable_objects.htm) which supports full **CRUD** operations on external data.

Check the release notes for full details. but here's a quikie

[image]

Comment: Great news really :) 
Thank you for the help and for the very good news